# Export-Csv issue, AD groups containing more then 1 user displays as System.Object[]

Tags: powershell

I am taking a stab at power shell to help in day to day administration and I thought it would be fun to write a script that will:

- Search for all security groups withing a specified search base (so I don't get a bunch of system groups that aren't what I'm interested in).
- Get all of the group memberships from each group that is found in the search.
- Dump everything to a CSV file.

Simple enough right?

I did some searching on the interwebs for similar projects and was able to put together a script that almost does what I need.

```bsh
## Search for all the groups and store them in $ADGroupList[]
$ADGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=Security Groups,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=local" |
               Select Name -ExpandProperty Name |
               Sort 

## Look at each element and do a couple things
$AdGroupList = @(foreach ($Group in $ADGroupList) {
    ## Object to store each group name and their memberships
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        GroupName = $Group.Name
        Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group |
                  Select SamAccountName -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
    }
})

## Save all the created objects to the CSV
$AdGroupList | Export-Csv -Path C:\scripts\AdGroupList.csv
```

With the script as it is I get

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"GroupName","Members"
"group1","ad_user"
"group2","System.Object[]"
"group3","System.Object[]"
"group4","ad_user"
"group5","System.Object[]"
...
```

As you can see, groups with only 1 member display that user in plain text.
However larger groups with more members will display `System.Object[]` instead.

Doing a little more looking I tried a few things to try and expand the sys.obj's by use of modifying the Export.CSV

```bsh
$AdGroupList |
    Select-Object Server, @{Expression={$_.Members.Name -join ';'}} |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\scripts\AdGroupList.csv
```

But that doesn't display anything useful as it only works on the created object and I couldn't nail down how to delve further into each item.

I also tried creating a nested forloop to output each samaccountname in the object and adding it to the object to be displayed.
But, I can't get it to work due to a syntax error. I'm not sure what variable I need to use as an equivalent to `$group` for the users... I tried `$user`, `$samaccountname` and `$name`.

```bsh
foreach($Group in $ADGroupList) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        GroupName = $Group.Name
        $MembersList = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group |
                       Select SamAccountName -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
        foreach ($Name in $MembersList) {
            Members = $SamAccountName.SamAccountName
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I really like the tools PS can give me but I just cant seem to figure it out fully.

Comment: AD groups return as a `System.Object[]` due to returning as an array.  Iterate through any `System.Object[]` and handle each of those individual accounts like you would if they were a single one.

Comment: Right, which i tried as a nested forloop. Im aware sys.obj is an array, i'm looking for an effective means of doing just that... I prefaced this thread with, "I am taking a stab at power shell" implying i'm less familiar with its syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashtables don't work the way you're trying to build them. Change

```bsh
[PSCustomObject]@{
    GroupName = $Group.Name
    $MembersList = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group |
                   Select SamAccountName -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
    foreach ($Name in $MembersList) {
        Members = $SamAccountName.SamAccountName
    }
}
```

into

```bsh
[PSCustomObject]@{
    GroupName = $Group.Name
    Members   = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group |
                Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName) -join ','
}
```

Comment: OH, i see, so i needed to run the commandlet WITHIN the variable assignment. That makes sense, thanks Boss.